# Python multiple inheritance and MRO

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I'm currently studying for a python exam but I don't understand MRO and linearization in Python 3 yet.

```
class F: pass 
class G: pass 
class H: pass
class E(G,H): pass
class D(E,F): pass 
class C(E,G): pass
class B(C,H): pass
class A(D,B,E): pass
```

For example in one assignment theres a question whether it is possible for E to occur BEFORE C in the linearization of class A.

How do I determine whether it is possible? How could one describe the linearization algorithm (C3) as easy as possible? 
I'd be really thankful for all kinds of explanations and resources on this, as I'm having a hard time understanding linearization in Python.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 10):

### Python looks for parents or child classes in DFS order NOT IN BFS

```
# This order is called Method Resolution Order (`mro()`)

class A(object):
    def dothis(self):
        print('Doing this in A')

class B(A):
    pass

class C(object):
    def dothis(self):
        print('Doing this in C')

class D(B, C):
    pass

d_instance = D()
d_instance.dothis()
# METHOD RESOLUTION ORDER
print(D.mro())

'''
OUTPUT:

# Doing this in A
# [<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>]

    A

    |               C

    B(A)          /
        \
            D(B, C)

RESOLUTION ORDER IS (DFS) = D-B-A-C



             A

        /       \

    B(A)         C(A)
        \       /
            D(B, C)

If the same class appears in mro, the earlier occurrences get removed
D-B-A-C-A -> D-B-C-A, hence still a DFS
RESOLUTION ORDER IS (In Diamond shape) = D-B-C-A


'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Class E inherit from G and H.

classes G and H dependent (they don't inherit from anybody).

Because class E has no dependency on class C, he can be initialize before him

Comment: When I call print(A.__mro__) C appears before E though. Why?

Comment: @thedood this is because class C inherit from class E. this means that class C must be initialized before class E. in conclusion, you can create class E before class C but when you create Class C you must have Class E because class E inherit on class C